# Extracting a string from a substring in bash (yes, that way around)

Tags: string, bash, slice

I have a string of several words in bash called `comp_line`, which can have any number of spaces inside. For example:

```
"foo bar   apple  banana q xy"
```

And I have a zero-based index `comp_point` pointing to one character in that string, e.g. if `comp_point` is 4, it points to the first 'b' in 'bar'.

Based on the `comp_point` and `comp_line` alone, I want to extract the word being pointed to by the index, where the "word" is a sequence of letters, numbers, punctuation or any other non-whitespace character, surrounded by whitespace on either side (if the word is at the start or end of the string, or is the only word in the string, it should work the same way.)

The word I'm trying to extract will become `cur` (the current word)

Based on this, I've come up with a set of rules:

Read the current character `curchar`, the previous character `prevchar`, and the next character `nextchar`. Then:

1. If `curchar` is a graph character (non-whitespace), set `cur` to the letters before and after `curchar` (stopping until you reach a whitespace or string start/end on either side.)
2. Else, if `prevchar` is a graph character, set `cur` to the letters from the previous letter, backwards until the previous whitespace character/string start.
3. Else, if `nextchar` is a graph character, set `cur` to the letters from the next letter, forwards until the next whitespace character/string end.
4. If none of the above conditions are hit (meaning `curchar`, `nextchar` and `prevchar` are all whitespace characters,) set `cur` to `""` (empty string)

I've written some code which I think achieves this. Rules 2, 3 and 4 are relatively straightforward, but rule 1 is the most difficult to implement - I've had to do some complicated string slicing. I'm not convinced that my solution is in any way ideal, and want to know if anyone knows of a better way to do this within bash only (not outsourcing to Python or another easier language.)

Tested on https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler

```
#!/bin/bash
# GNU bash, version 4.4.20

comp_line="foo bar   apple  banana q xy"
comp_point=19
cur=""

curchar=${comp_line:$comp_point:1}
prevchar=${comp_line:$((comp_point - 1)):1}
nextchar=${comp_line:$((comp_point + 1)):1}
echo "<$prevchar> <$curchar> <$nextchar>"

if [[ $curchar =~ [[:graph:]] ]]; then
    # Rule 1 - Extract current word
    slice="${comp_line:$comp_point}"
    endslice="${slice%% *}"
    slice="${slice#"$endslice"}"
    slice="${comp_line%"$slice"}"
    cur="${slice##* }"
else
    if [[ $prevchar =~ [[:graph:]] ]]; then
        # Rule 2 - Extract previous word
        slice="${comp_line::$comp_point}"
        cur="${slice##* }"
    else
        if [[ $nextchar =~ [[:graph:]] ]]; then
            # Rule 3 - Extract next word
            slice="${comp_line:$comp_point+1}"
            cur="${slice%% *}"
        else
            # Rule 4 - Set cur to empty string ""
            cur=""
        fi
    fi
fi

echo "Cur: <$cur>"
```

The current example will return 'banana' as `comp_point` is set to 19.

I'm sure that there must be a neater way to do it that I hadn't thought of, or some trick that I've missed. Also it works so far, but I think there may be some edge cases I hadn't thought of. Can anyone advise if there's a better way to do it?

---

(The XY problem, if anyone asks)

I'm writing a tab completion script, and trying to emulate the functionality of COMP_WORDS and COMP_CWORD, using COMP_LINE and COMP_POINT. When a user is typing a command to tab complete, I want to work out which word they are trying to tab complete just based on the latter two variables. I don't want to outsource this code to Python because performance takes a big hit when Python is involved in tab complete.

Comment: It's really refreshing to see someone pour that much work into writing a question. Thank you. However, I'm wondering why you don't use `COMP_CWORD` in the first place. Could this be another / the actual XY problem?

Comment: Thank you! The wider context is: bash tab completion has a quirk where it splits command words into `COMP_WORDS` based on the contents of `COMP_WORDBREAKS`, which contains a colon and several other characters. The commands I'm writing completion for use colons. I've had to engineer a roundabout solution which involves joining `COMP_WORDS` into a single string and splitting it on spaces again. But then I need to correctly identify where the user's cursor is, and if the user is selecting an empty space character, add an empty string back into `COMP_WORDS` at the correct position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if anyone knows of a better way to do this within bash only

Use regexes. With `^.{4}` you can skip the first four letters to navigate to index 4. With `[[:graph:]]*` you can match the rest of the word at that index. `*` is greedy and will match as many graphical characters as possible.

```
wordAtIndex() {
  local index=$1 string=$2 left right indexFromRight
  [[ "$string" =~ ^.{$index}([[:graph:]]*) ]]
  right=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  ((indexFromRight=${#string}-index-1))
  [[ "$string" =~ ([[:graph:]]*).{$indexFromRight}$ ]]
  left=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  echo "$left${right:1}"
}
```

And here is full test for your example:

```
string="foo bar   apple  banana q xy"
for ((i=0; i < "${#string}"; ++i)); do
  printf '%s <-- "%s"\n' "${string:i:1}" "$(wordAtIndex "$i" "$string")"
done
```

This outputs the input string vertically on the left, and on each index extracts the word that index points to on the right.

```
f <-- "foo"
o <-- "foo"
o <-- "foo"
  <-- ""
b <-- "bar"
a <-- "bar"
r <-- "bar"
  <-- ""
  <-- ""
  <-- ""
a <-- "apple"
p <-- "apple"
p <-- "apple"
l <-- "apple"
e <-- "apple"
  <-- ""
  <-- ""
b <-- "banana"
a <-- "banana"
n <-- "banana"
a <-- "banana"
n <-- "banana"
a <-- "banana"
  <-- ""
q <-- "q"
  <-- ""
x <-- "xy"
y <-- "xy"
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I haven't yet had the time to test it, but it looks like a good solution. Your test doesn't match my requirements currently - the space character after "apple" should return "apple", and the space character before "banana" should return "banana", for example. Only the second space in between "bar" and "apple" should return an empty space as it has a space before and after it. But I'm sure I can tinker with your solution to get my requirements sorted out.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what the double square bracket `[[]]` syntax does. Ordinarily I'd use that in an if statement, or with `&&` or `||`. What does it do when you have double square brackets on their own?

Comment: I've just realised I've been silly. Your solution solves Rule 1 of my original solution, which was the main thing I was trying to optimise. I can still use my original solution for Rules 2, 3 and 4 with no problem. So this should work great :). Thanks!

Comment: @Lou I'm happy this worked for your. Regarding the `[[ ]]` without `if`, `&&`, `||`: The `[[` is a built-in command, just like `cd`, or `read`. It's most common use-case is based on its exit status (e.g. `if [[ ... ]]`, or `[[ ... ]] &&`) but there is more than just the exit status. our case of `[[ string =~ ^.a(b*) ]]` the variable `BASH_REMATCH` is set and allows us to extract only part of what was matched. `BASH_REMATCH[1]` refers to the group `(b*)`.

Comment: Thanks! I did some more testing and eventually figured out what was going on. There's still a lot of subtle nuances to bash that I'm taking my time to get my head around.

Answer (score 2):

Another way in bash without array.

```
#!/bin/bash

string="foo bar   apple  banana q xy"

wordAtIndex() {
  local index=$1 string=$2 ret='' last first
  if [ "${string:index:1}" != " " ] ; then
    last="${string:index}"
    first="${string:0:index}"
    ret="${first##* }${last%% *}"
  fi
  echo "$ret"
}

for ((i=0; i < "${#string}"; ++i)); do
 printf '%s <-- "%s"\n' "${string:i:1}" "$(wordAtIndex "$i" "$string")"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Though I'm curious at some of your syntax as well. Why the parentheses around the `[ ]` in your if condition? And for that matter, don't people usually advise to use double square brackets `[[ ]]` instead? Or is there a preference to use single in your case?

Comment: @Lou You are right, no need of parentheses here. I update the answer. I usually use sh not bash where [[ ]] is not available. It' a simple test here so no need of use extended bash test here.